# Java native, char**

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface

i am trying to call method `BS2_GetUserList(...)` https://kb.supremainc.com/bs2sdk/doku.php?id=en:bs2_getuserlist from java.

```
IntByReference uidsObj = new IntByReference();
IntByReference numUid = new IntByReference();
IntByReference ptrIsAcceptableUserID = null;
bs.BS2_GetUserList(context.getValue(), deviceId.getValue(), uidsObj, numUid, ptrIsAcceptableUserID))
```

It works, i can read `numUid` (2).
But please, can someone give me hits how i should work with `uidsObj` (`char**`) i can get value from it (for example 726004496), which is pointer to array of chars (i think)? I need to read values (ids) from it.

Thanks

Comment: If you have your `BS2_GetUserList` method implemented in Java, you can  see what parameter type of `uidsObj` is required for Java method. If it's an char array then you should convert your `IntByReference uidsObj` to java char array, if it's another object then convert it to it.

Comment: i implemented ´BS2_GetUserList´ as java native method, uidsObj can be IntByReference, int[]... but still with same result